# Alpha numeric detection from .svg image

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Was wondering if anyone ran into a problem similar to mine and had some sort of solution they could share.

I have a .svg that looks somewhat like the below image.

[image]

My goal is to extract the ID "1214A" and any other unique ID's in the similar format from this .svg image. ***(only showed a sample of the image, there are other ID's in the image with the ID being inside that oval shape as well.)***

Below is what the .svg looks like.

http://jsfiddle.net/rayshinn/1wgob3qu/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="692px" height="924px" viewBox="0 0 692 924" overflow="inherit" xml:space="preserve">
<rect x="352.62" y="456.78" fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="10.2" height="8.159"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M362.82,456.78"/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    352.62,464.939 362.82,464.939 352.62,471.061 352.62,464.939 362.82,471.061 352.62,471.061 "/>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    355.5,453.42 355.5,456.78 362.82,456.78 362.82,440.46 346.5,440.46 346.5,447.78 349.859,447.78 "/>
<rect x="325.26" y="475.02" fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="8.88" height="8.762"/>
<rect x="362.82" y="456.78" fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="0.84" height="14.279"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M362.82,471.061"/>
<rect x="362.82" y="440.46" fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="0.84" height="16.32"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M362.82,456.78"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="362.82" y1="471.061" x2="362.82" y2="464.939"/>
<rect x="362.82" y="440.46" fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="4.08" height="23.28"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M366.9,463.74"/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    345.78,452.82 346.26,452.82 346.5,453.06 346.62,453.3 346.5,453.54 "/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="345.78" y1="452.82" x2="343.38" y2="455.34"/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    343.38,455.82 343.26,455.58 343.38,455.34 "/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="343.38" y1="455.82" x2="343.62" y2="456.06"/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    346.5,453.54 344.1,456.06 343.86,456.18 343.62,456.06 "/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="346.5" y1="453.06" x2="346.98" y2="453.06"/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    344.46,459.18 343.5,457.86 343.02,456.42 "/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    344.94,458.7 344.1,457.62 343.62,456.3 "/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    346.98,453.06 347.58,453.3 349.26,454.5 "/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    343.26,455.94 343.5,456.06 343.62,456.3 "/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    343.02,456.42 343.02,456.06 343.26,455.94 "/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="347.82" y1="460.5" x2="347.34" y2="460.74"/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    347.46,460.02 347.7,460.14 347.82,460.5 "/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    349.26,454.5 350.46,456.18 350.7,456.78 "/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    347.46,460.02 346.14,459.66 344.94,458.7 "/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    347.34,460.74 345.78,460.26 344.46,459.18 "/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="350.7" y1="456.78" x2="350.7" y2="457.26"/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    347.7,460.14 347.58,459.9 347.7,459.66 350.1,457.26 "/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="347.939" y1="460.38" x2="347.7" y2="460.14"/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    348.42,460.38 348.18,460.5 347.939,460.38 "/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="350.82" y1="457.98" x2="348.42" y2="460.38"/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    350.1,457.26 350.34,457.14 350.58,457.26 350.82,457.5 350.939,457.74 350.82,457.98 "/>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    346.86,448.14 346.86,451.02 352.26,456.42 355.141,456.42 355.141,453.54 349.74,448.14 "/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
    334.14,483.78 338.58,483.78 338.34,482.46 337.74,481.26 336.78,480.3 335.46,479.58 334.14,479.34 335.46,479.22 336.78,478.5 
    337.74,477.54 338.34,476.34 338.58,475.02 334.14,475.02 "/>
<rect x="325.26" y="462.78" fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.36" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="6.12" height="12.238"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#BBBBBB" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="330.18" y1="472.5" x2="331.38" y2="475.02"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.36" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="331.74" y1="471.54" x2="331.74" y2="465.78"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M348.779,461.94h0.36l0.119,0.119h0.12v0.12h0.12c0.596,0.552-0.116,0.049,0.479,0.601v0.12h0.119v0.24l0.121,0.119v0.12h0.119v0.24
    l0.12,0.12v0.119l0.12,0.12v0.24l0.12,0.119v0.36l0.12,0.12v0.239l0.118,0.119v0.48l0.121,0.239v0.479l0.119,0.12v0.479l0.12,0.24
    v0.84l0.12,0.119v0.36c0,0.521,0,1.04,0,1.56v1.08c0,0.44,0,0.881,0,1.32v0.358l-0.12,0.121v0.959l-0.12,0.121v0.479l-0.119,0.239
    v0.479l-0.121,0.12v0.479l-0.118,0.119v0.24l-0.12,0.24v0.239l-0.12,0.119v0.24l-0.12,0.121v0.119l-0.12,0.12v0.239l-0.119,0.12
    v0.119H350.1v0.24l-0.239,0.24v0.121h-0.119v0.119l-0.36,0.36h-0.12v0.119h-0.239l-0.119,0.121h-0.36V479.1h-0.24v-0.118h-0.12
    l-0.6-0.602v-0.12l-0.12-0.119v-0.121l-0.239-0.238v-0.24l-0.12-0.12v-0.24l-0.12-0.118v-0.121l-0.12-0.119v-0.24l-0.12-0.12v-0.359
    l-0.12-0.119v-0.48l-0.12-0.12V474.9l-0.12-0.121V474.3l-0.12-0.239v-0.841l-0.119-0.239v-1.561l-0.12-0.24v-1.319l0.12-0.119
    v-1.681l0.119-0.239v-0.12c-0.065-1.05,0.167-0.518,0.12-1.32l0.12-0.239v-0.479l0.12-0.12v-0.479l0.12-0.12V464.7l0.12-0.12v-0.36
    l0.12-0.12v-0.118l0.12-0.121v-0.239l0.12-0.12v-0.12l0.119-0.12v-0.119l0.12-0.12v-0.12h0.12v-0.24h0.12v-0.12l0.36-0.36h0.118
    v-0.119h0.12v-0.12L348.779,461.94"/>
<polyline fill="#010101" points="349.62,465.3 349.62,465.061 349.141,465.061 349.26,465.061 349.26,465.3 349.38,465.3 
    349.38,465.54 349.5,465.54 349.5,465.66 349.62,465.66 349.62,465.78 "/>
<polyline fill="#010101" points="350.221,466.141 350.221,465.78 350.1,465.78 349.74,465.42 349.74,465.3 349.62,465.3 
    349.62,465.78 347.34,465.78 347.34,466.141 "/>
<path fill="#010101" d="M349.98,468.78v-0.841v0.239l-0.121,0.12v0.12h-0.119v0.12h-0.48l-0.119-0.12h-0.121v-0.12H348.9v-0.12
    h-0.121v-0.119h-0.119v-0.12h-0.12v-0.119c-0.2-0.2-0.399-0.4-0.601-0.602h-0.119v-0.12h-0.12l-0.12-0.118h-0.24v1.92h0.36v-1.44
    v0.12h0.12l0.239,0.24l0.119,0.119l0.12,0.12v0.119h0.12v0.12h0.12v0.12h0.12v0.12l0.119,0.12h0.121v0.12h0.239v0.12h0.601
    l0.119-0.12"/>
<polyline fill="#010101" points="350.221,467.939 350.221,467.58 350.1,467.46 350.1,467.34 349.98,467.34 349.98,467.22 
    349.859,467.22 349.74,467.1 349.38,467.1 349.38,467.46 349.74,467.46 349.74,467.58 349.859,467.58 349.859,467.7 349.98,467.7 
    349.98,468.78 349.98,468.66 350.1,468.66 350.1,468.54 350.221,468.54 350.221,468.061 "/>
<polyline fill="#010101" points="349.62,469.859 349.62,469.62 349.141,469.62 349.26,469.62 349.26,469.859 349.38,469.859 
    349.38,470.1 349.5,470.1 349.5,470.22 349.62,470.22 349.62,470.34 "/>
<polyline fill="#010101" points="350.221,470.7 350.221,470.34 350.1,470.34 349.98,470.22 349.859,470.1 349.74,469.98 
    349.74,469.859 349.62,469.859 349.62,470.34 347.34,470.34 347.34,470.7 "/>
<polyline fill="#010101" points="350.221,473.1 350.221,472.859 348.42,471.42 348.061,471.42 348.061,472.74 347.34,472.74 
    347.34,473.1 348.061,473.1 348.061,473.46 348.42,473.46 348.42,471.78 349.74,472.74 "/>
<polyline fill="#010101" points="350.221,473.1 349.74,472.74 348.42,472.74 348.42,471.78 348.42,473.1 "/>
<polyline fill="#010101" points="350.221,475.26 350.221,474.78 347.34,473.7 347.34,474.061 348.18,474.42 348.18,475.62 
    348.54,474.54 349.38,474.9 349.74,474.9 349.74,475.02 349.98,475.02 "/>
<polyline fill="#010101" points="350.221,475.26 349.98,475.02 349.74,475.02 349.74,475.141 349.5,475.141 349.38,475.26 
    348.54,475.5 348.54,474.54 348.18,475.62 347.34,475.98 347.34,476.46 "/>
</svg>
```

This .svg image was autogenerated by using the export feature Adobe Illustrator from PDF to .svg.

Is there a way to extract the ID in this picture using Javascript and store it in to some array?

Thank you for reading, any starting points or any sort of help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: My gut tells me that there's a way to get the ID before the PDF to SVG step. I don't know what that way is, though.

Comment: @AustinMullins ah interesting. I wonder.hmm.

Answer (score 0):

As @austin-mullins suggests, it could be that the PDF contains the original text, which would be easier to extract.  However this sample looks like it originates from a CAD drawing, so I suspect it probably doesn't.

Another approach would be to recognise characters from their definitions.  For example the digit "1" (at 90 degrees) is the following element:

```
<polyline fill="#010101"
          points="350.221,466.141 350.221,465.78 350.1,465.78 349.74,465.42
                  349.74,465.3 349.62,465.3 349.62,465.78 347.34,465.78
                  347.34,466.141"></polyline>
```

If you subtract the initial point (350.221,466.141) from each set of coords in the polyline, you should be able to recognise other "1" characters in the document.  At least those at 90 degrees.

That should work for the whole document.  And the extracted character templates may even work for other documents if you need to do that.